# looking for open source tools

Tags: gis, arcgis, lidar-data

Do you know any tools available for the conversion of LAS (LIDAR data) into Voronoi diagrams or TIN (triangular irregular networks) available?

Or can anyone can suggest how to do it in arcgis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [LIDAR data processing with open source tools](http://www.perrygeo.net/wordpress/?p=38)

Answer (score 0):

This may help a bit. In ArcGIS, you can either use an actual TIN which is a file format, or you can use a Terrain which is better suited for high density point clouds such as LIDAR. It offers better performance over a TIN.

The Terrain can be used where you need a TIN.

[Loading surface feature data points into a geodatabase](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/tutorials/3d_analyst/3D_45.htm)

Instead of the ASCII tool shown in the above guide, you will need to use the [LAS to Multiple](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=1121&pid=1118&topicname=LAS_To_Multipoint_(3D_Analyst)) tool.