# tools for viewing TIN files

Tags: geometry, gis, lidar-data

is there any free open source tools available for viewing TIN (triangular irregular networks) files( which i got from LAS (Lidar data) file...)?

thanks!

Comment: This question is very similar to, but not quite the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341850/looking-for-open-source-tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend greatly on the format.  Most TINs generated from LIDAR data will be in one of the standard GIS formats, in which case a good, open source GIS program will be your best bet.  Any of the packages which use the GDAL/OGR libraries will most likely be able to handle the TIN format you're using (whether that's ArcInfo's, etc).

I'd recommend trying either [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) (either to learn) or [GRASS](http://grass.itc.it/) (supports the most options/formats).

Answer (score 0):

You might try this [website](http://jca3.freeshell.org/tinlib/tinlib.html).  It seems they have some tools and libraries that may work for you.

Comment: That's for creating a tin, not necessarily viewing one that's already generated.